How to set in Entity Framework Core a joining table and save via API?
In my project, I use a database-first approach. I have a class for Sessions that requires to have one or more values from another table called Explanation.
public class Session : Table 
{
    public IList<SessionExplanations>? SessionExplanations { get; set; }
}

public class Explanation : Table
{
    public IList<SessionExplanations>? SessionExplanations { get; set; }
}

[PrimaryKey(nameof(SessionId), nameof(ExplanationId))]
public class SessionExplanations
{
    public long SessionId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("SessionId")]
    public Session? Session { get; set; }

    public long ExplanationId {  get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ExplanationId")]
    public Explanation? Explanation { get; set; }
}

From a page, I fill a form and select one or more Explanation to associate with this Session. I have a Minimal API to save the Session to the database.
If the record is new, I don't have an ID. So, I don't know how to form the JSON as the payload in order to save the session and all the details in the joining table.
In the API, do I have to split the save in 2 parts, first save the Session and when I have the ID, save the data in the joining table?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships/many-to-many You only need to know the collection of ExplanationId values. Assign the rest of the navigation properties and everything should work.

When you create a new Session that should be linked to various existing Explanations you can create an API endpoint that receives a dto containing the Session data and a list of ExplanationIds.
From this dto, create a Session object and assign SessionExplanations that consist of SessionExplanation objects in which only ExplanationId is set.
EF will notice that these SessionExplanations belong to the Session and set their SessionIds while saving changes, all in one transaction that EF manages itself.
